# check whether a number is prime or not?

Tags: php, primes, prime-factoring

For checking whether a number is a prime or not, wouldn't be enough to check if it is divisible by 2, 3, 5, and 7? 
While looking at other programs on the internet, I have found that people are checking the factors till the number, or half of the number or till the square root of the number.

```
if ( ($number%2 ==0) || ($number%3==0) || ($number%5==0) || ($number%7)==0) )
    echo "not a prime";
```

The above check would suffice right? Any thoughts? ignore the prime numbers 2, 3, 5, 7 for now.

Comment: Did you check this function `gmp_prob_prime()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not enough. For example a prime number 11 is not divisible by 2, 3, 5, and 7. And not a prime number 121 is not divisble by 2, 3, 5, and 7, but is divisible by 11. See the definition of the [prime number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number).